# Find integer a,b > 1 such that $2^a + 3^b = 2^{a+b} +1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to know if it is possible to find an integer solution to

$2^a + 3^b = 2^{a+b} +1$

with $a,b > 1$

Comment: Any thoughts about the problem?

Comment: a solution would imply a counterexample for the collatz conjecture, maybe. I just have no idea if there is some way to solve this equation.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$2^a(2^b - 1) = (3-1)(1 + 3 + 3^2 + \ldots + 3^{b-1}),$$ so
$$2^{a-1}(2^b - 1) = (1 + 3 + 3^2 + \ldots + 3^{b-1}).$$

Considering the second equation mod $3$ we thus see that $2^{a-1}$ and $2^b - 1$ aren't zero. As $2^b$ isn't zero mod $3$ either, it must be $2$ mod $3$, i.e. $b$ must be odd.

But this implies that $1 + 3 + 3^2 + \ldots + 3^{b-1}$ is $2$ mod $4$ and hence (from the first equality in this answer) that $a = 2$.

But there are no solutions with $a = 2$, since then we have $4 - 1 + 3^b = 2^{a+b}$ and the two sides are different modulo $3$.

Comment: Sorry, why $2^b -1$ mod 3 can not be zero?

Comment: the rhs of the second equation is 1 mod 3 and $2^b - 1$ divides the lhs

Comment: and why they must be inverse?

Comment: their product is 1 mod 3, as the rhs is visibly 1 mod 3

Comment: the inverseness doesn't matter, it was confusing before, sorry. i cleaned up a bit just now.

Comment: I fully understood, thank you.